# Count array items by month and year

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am getting dates in json of multiple parcels. the dates usually tells on which date and time that particular parcels was created. So with that date **I want to count number of parcels created in each month**. I have never done this before and i am not sure what thread of stackoverflow can help me out in this regard. I would very much appreciate any explanation to solve this help or a code reference.
Here is my sample JSON result

```
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2019-12-30T04:36:05.001Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2019-12-06T08:58:23.030Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2020-01-08T19:00:21.873Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2020-01-10T14:55:50.781Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2019-12-21T13:05:09.983Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2020-01-15T12:10:20.316Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2020-01-14T06:47:36.078Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2020-02-15-T06:47:36.078Z"
  }
]
```

I am working with angular so i am getting this data from my service. So now i need to show month wise total number of parcels created.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @NinaScholz nope i did not as i am not sure from where do i need to start.

Comment: i even don't see any `parcel` in the data. what result do you expect? btw, [JSON](https://json.org/) is a string.

Comment: @NinaScholz I am filtering them out when hitting the api through service because i do not need details of parcel but only the creation date of those parcels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a part of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string as key and count with an object.

```js
var data = [{ createdAt: "2019-12-30T04:36:05.001Z" }, { createdAt: "2019-12-06T08:58:23.030Z" }, { createdAt: "2020-01-08T19:00:21.873Z" }, { createdAt: "2020-01-10T14:55:50.781Z" }, { createdAt: "2019-12-21T13:05:09.983Z" }, { createdAt: "2020-01-15T12:10:20.316Z" }, { createdAt: "2020-01-14T06:47:36.078Z" }, { createdAt: "2020-02-15-T06:47:36.078Z" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { createdAt }) => {
        var key = createdAt.slice(0, 7);
        r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @ahsannissar: While this one is faster and shorter than [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59820107/11299053), you need to bear in mind that this will work properly for ISO-formatted dates, so if you got something, like `15-Jun-2020', you'll require some more general solution.

Comment: @yevgenGorbunkov you are right but i won't be getting dates in any other format from backend so for now this one is fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to summarize your records.

```js
const src = [{"createdAt":"2019-12-30T04:36:05.001Z"},{"createdAt":"2019-12-06T08:58:23.030Z"},{"createdAt":"2020-01-08T19:00:21.873Z"},{"createdAt":"2020-01-10T14:55:50.781Z"},{"createdAt":"2019-12-21T13:05:09.983Z"},{"createdAt":"2020-01-15T12:10:20.316Z"},{"createdAt":"2020-01-14T06:47:36.078Z"},{"createdAt":"2020-02-15T06:47:36.078Z"}],
      summary = src.reduce((res,{createdAt}) => {
        const year = new Date(createdAt).getFullYear(),
              month = new Date(createdAt).getMonth()+1           
        res[`${year}-${month}`] = (res[`${year}-${month}`] || 0) + 1
        return res
      }, {})
      
console.log(summary)
```

**Note**, above will work if your `createdAt` strings formatted in any way that may be parsed by `new Date()` constructor, not only ISO-formatted date.

Comment: I will save this snippet for future. Quite a good solution for playing with different formats